# Move Network Folder to users One_Drive folder drive via Active Directory User Entries. Powershell or C#

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, onedrive, file-copying

I have multiple users in an Active directory system structure.

Each user has a network share folder in their own name on a fileserver.
UsersFolders\Username.

I need to for each user in my active directory OU move their FileServer\UsersFolders\Username folder with all of its content to that Users One Drive Folder UsersOne-Drive\UserFileServerFolder ..

How can I do this with Powershell or C#?

Comment: I'd suggest writing a script for us to assist with, as compared to writing one for you. 

For "how to start", it depends on how dodgy you want to get, but I'd write a logon script to 1) check the user's OneDrive Path variable (to ensure OneDrive is set up) 2) Check the user's network share is accessible / exists 3) copy or move to the OneDrive folder (robocopy or xcopy could also work)

Comment: @GuyS any idea how this "check the user's OneDrive Path variable " is done .. I am searching online and finding things that might require more credentials than I would like.  I prefer the easiest way to do this .. on say 1000 computers / users at a time  so for each ou in AD , test OneDrive (how?) , then if exists Test Network Folder exist , move from Network to OneDrive .. I only need to know how to go about the first test - One Drive exists .. prefer limited credentials .. as for the logon .. probably will push it that way.

Comment: If it's a logon script, it should run under the user context, and you can use the `$env:OneDrive` variable. For me, it resolves to "C:\users\myusername\OneDrive"

Comment: Awesome Thanks .. that will get me going to what I need.